# Issue Dockerising Django + Celery... Unable to load celery application

Tags: django, docker, redis, celery, gunicorn

I'm having a slight issue with spinning up a Dockerised stack of: Django, Redis, Celery on a server backbone of nginx and gunicorn. The Django application connects to an external PostgreSQL database.

I have the following `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./django
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - "8000"
    volumes:

      - django-static:/usr/src/app/static
      - django-uploads:/usr/src/app/uploads
    depends_on:
      - redis
    links:
      - redis:redis
    environment:
      ...

    command: /usr/src/app/wave.sh

  nginx:
    build:
      context: nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ssl_data:/etc/resty-auto-ssl
    environment:
      ALLOWED_DOMAINS: "${STAGING_ALLOWED_DOMAINS}"
      SITES: "${STAGING_SITES}"

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'

  celery:
    build: ./django
    command: celery --app=Wave.celery.app worker --loglevel=DEBUG

    environment:
      ...

    volumes:
      - './django:/usr/src/app/'
    links:
      - redis:redis
    depends_on:
      - web
      - redis
      - nginx
    restart: on-failure

  celery-beat:
    build: ./django
    command: celery --app=Wave.celery.app beat --loglevel=DEBUG

    environment:
      ...

    volumes:
      - './django:/usr/src/app/'
    links:
      - redis:redis
    depends_on:
      - web
      - redis
      - nginx
    restart: on-failure

volumes:
  ssl_data:
  django-static:
  django-uploads:
```

However, on utilising:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.wave-api-staging.yml up --build --force-recreate
```

The `wave.sh` script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -rf celerybeat.pid

ln -s /run/shm /dev/shm

python3 manage.py collectstatic --no-input
python3 manage.py migrate
python3 manage.py shell < createsuperuser.py

pip3 freeze

/usr/local/bin/gunicorn Wave.wsgi:application --timeout 3600 --log-level=DEBUG -w 5 -b :8000
```

Which replaces the following `command` instruction in the `web` service:

`command: bash -c "rm -rf celerybeat.pid && python3 manage.py makemigrations && python3 manage.py migrate --run-syncdb && python3 manage.py shell < createsuperuser.py && python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"`

`celery.py`:

```
import os

import datetime

from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Wave.settings')

app = Celery('Wave', include=['amq.v1.SurfTaskRunner.demand', 'amq.v1.SurfTaskRunner.periodic'])

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(minute='6,16,26,36,46,56', hour='*', day_of_week='*', day_of_month='*'),
        dispatch_surfers_waivers_periodic_task.s(),
    )

@app.task(bind=True)
def dispatch_surfers_waivers_periodic_task(self):
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.7.2-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron && apt-get -y install nano

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./wave.sh /usr/src/app/wave.sh

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/src/app/wave.sh"]

COPY . /usr/src/app
```

---

I receive the following errors from the celery and celery beat services:

```
celery_1       | Error: 
celery_1       | Unable to load celery application.
celery_1       | The module Wave was not found.
celery-beat_1  | Error: 
celery-beat_1  | Unable to load celery application.
celery-beat_1  | The module Wave was not found.
```

I have tried reading and google extensively, but so far have found zero clues as to what could be going wrong here...I'm at the point of completely ditching Celery if I can't get this to work?

However, the same process can be spun up locally without nginx, and with the standard `python manage.py runserver` command.

---

Update: here is my local development docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: ./django
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8982:8982
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
      - redis:redis
    command: bash -c "rm -rf celerybeat.pid && python3 manage.py makemigrations && python3 manage.py migrate --run-syncdb && python3 manage.py shell < createsuperuser.py && python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8982"
    volumes: ['./django:/usr/src/app/']
    environment:
        ...

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'

  celery:
    build: ./django
    command: celery -A Wave worker --loglevel=DEBUG

    environment:
        ...

    volumes:
      - './django:/usr/src/app/'
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
      - redis:redis
    depends_on:
      - django
      - postgres
      - redis
    restart: on-failure

  celery-beat:
    build: ./django
    command: celery -A Wave beat --loglevel=DEBUG

    environment:
        ...

    volumes:
      - './django:/usr/src/app/'
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
      - redis:redis
    depends_on:
      - django
      - postgres
      - redis
    restart: on-failure

  postgres:
    build:
      context: ./postgres
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=conveyor
      - POSTGRES_USER=conveyor
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=89$r55cP%fSDDghypoAsdd
```

Comment: Can you run celery locally without Docker by invoking `celery --app=Wave.celery.app worker --loglevel=DEBUG`? What is the output?

Comment: @OlzhasArystanov It works locally with a slightly different volume binding in the django application.

Comment: Post contents of your Dockerfile

Comment: @OlzhasArystanov I've updated my question with the local development file.

Comment: I meant your `Dockerfile` for building django and celery container, not `docker-compose`

Comment: @OlzhasArystanov Sorry, my mistake, included is the Dockerfile.

Comment: It looks OK. Can you also post the contents of your celery.py file?

Comment: @OlzhasArystanov Posted. I don't think there's anything wrong because this application with the celery and celery beat run fine locally. Just on the docker-machine.

Comment: It seems that your django and celery containers are being built differently. In your `docker-compose.yml`, you are passing `context` and `dockerfile` to `django` service but not to `celery`. Is it being made intentionally?

Comment: Just updating the docker-compose file to see if this is the issue.

Comment: @OlzhasArystanov After adding the build content to the docker-compose file I still get the same issue...

Comment: Try changing command for your celery service in `docker-compose.yml` to this: `celery -A Wave app=Wave.celery:app worker --loglevel=DEBUG`. And the same for celery beat respectively

Comment: @OlzhasArystanov Trying this now. Incidentally, I tried bash -c "ls -la" and all that was in the root directory of the `celery` and `celery_beat` services was `"static"` and `"uploads"...`

Comment: @OlzhasArystanov I removed the two volume bindings, but for some reason they still persist on the app level....

Comment: @MichealJ.Roberts were you able to get it fixed?

Comment: @Sandhu Yeh, in the end. Very tricky and fiddly setup tho.

Comment: it got fixed for me when I gave `build: \ context: ./backend \  dockerfile: Dockerfile` instead of using backend image...